# Prevent content in each UICollectionViewCell in UICollectionView from changing as I scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As I scroll back and forth in the UICollectionView, I notice that the content changes in the cells that appear and disappear on the screen.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
I just want to load all of the content to each cell appropriately and then prevent it from changing as I scroll.

Here's some of the code related to this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    if (!label) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        label.tag = 100;
        label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not supplying the content for the label in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Remember, these cells are being *reused*. So even if the label already exists, you need to supply the label text, because the cell is now being used in a different row and therefore needs different text!

So just move this line:

```
    label.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

...down and outside the `if` block, to just before you return the `cell`.